# Вывести на экран строки с максимальным и минимальным значением суммы

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста как именно осуществить главное условие, если я уже нашел сумму для каждой строки. Теперь нужно найти строки с максимальным и минимальным значением суммы. Как это все осуществляется,я знаю только как максимальный элемент находить,а именно со значением суммы всей строки без понятия,начинал делать получалась ахинея которая даже не запускалась:(. P.S Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void sum(int** V,int n,int m);   
void main()
{ 
// создание матрицы n строк m столбцов
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus"); 
    int n,m;
    cout<<"Количество строк :?";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Количество столбцов :?";
    cin>>m;
    int** V=new int*[n]; // выделение памяти
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        V[i]=new int[m];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            
            V[i][j] = rand() % 10; // генерируем случайные числа они в массиве будут от 0до10. // для ввода чисел в ручную используем cin>>V[i][j];
            cout<<V[i][j]<<"\t"; // вывод массива
       
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
   sum(V,n,m); 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // освобождение памяти массива
        delete[] V[i];
    delete[] V;
    system("pause");
    
}
 
void sum(int** V,int n,int m)
{
    int max,min;
    max=min=0;
    int max_index,min_index;
    max_index=min_index=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
             sum+=V[i][j]; // подсчет суммы в каждой строке
        }
        cout<<i+1<<" строка, сумма = " << sum<< endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для переносимости у `main` должен быть возвращаемый тип `int`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sum(int** V, int n, int m, int& min_index, int& max_index);

int main() {
    // создание матрицы n строк m столбцов
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    int n, m;
    cout << "Количество строк :?";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Количество столбцов :?";
    cin >> m;
    int** V = new int* [n]; // выделение памяти

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        V[i] = new int[m];
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            V[i][j] = rand() %
                      10; // генерируем случайные числа они в массиве будут от 0до10. // для ввода чисел в ручную используем cin>>V[i][j];
            cout << V[i][j] << "\t"; // вывод массива
            }

        cout << endl;
        }

    int min_index, max_index;
    sum(V, n, m, min_index, max_index);
    cout << "min line:\n";

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        cout << V[min_index][j] << "\t";

    cout << endl;
    cout << "max line:\n";

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        cout << V[max_index][j] << "\t";

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // освобождение памяти массива
        delete[] V[i];

    delete[] V;
    }

void sum(int** V, int n, int m, int& min_index, int& max_index) {
    int max, min;
    max = INT_MIN;
    min = INT_MAX;
    max_index = min_index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            sum += V[i][j]; // подсчет суммы в каждой строке
            }

        cout << i + 1 << " строка, сумма = " << sum << endl;

        if (sum > max) {
            max = sum;
            max_index = i;
            }

        if (sum < min) {
            min = sum;
            min_index = i;
            }
        }
    }
```